# Microphone is not recording with HifiBerry and Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, alsa, hifiberry, microphone, arecord

I installed the HifiBerry driver as specified. The Board is recognized and the audio output works fine. 
Just the audio input seems to be not working. I checked if the microphone is muted but I can't recognize any bad setting.
Here is the output of the amixer command:

```
Simple mixer control 'DSP Program',0
Capabilities: enum
Items: 'FIR interpolation with de-emphasis' 'Low latency IIR with de- 
emphasis' 'High attenuation with de-emphasis' 'Fixed process flow' 'Ringing-less low latency FIR'
Item0: 'FIR interpolation with de-emphasis'
Simple mixer control 'Analogue',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 1
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 1 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 1 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Analogue Playback Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 1
  Front Left: 1 [100%] [0.80dB]
  Front Right: 1 [100%] [0.80dB]
Simple mixer control 'Auto Mute',0
  Capabilities: pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [off]
  Front Right: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Auto Mute Mono',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
Simple mixer control 'Auto Mute Time Left',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: '21ms' '106ms' '213ms' '533ms' '1.07s' '2.13s' '5.33s'     '10.66s'
  Item0: '21ms'
Simple mixer control 'Auto Mute Time Right',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: '21ms' '106ms' '213ms' '533ms' '1.07s' '2.13s' '5.33s'     '10.66s'
  Item0: '213ms'
Simple mixer control 'Clock Missing Period',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: '1s' '2s' '3s' '4s' '5s' '6s' '7s' '8s'
  Item0: '1s'
Simple mixer control 'Deemphasis',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Digital',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 207
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 207 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 207 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Max Overclock DAC',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 40
     Mono: 40 [100%]
    Simple mixer control 'Max Overclock DSP',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
Limits: 0 - 40
  Mono: 40 [100%]
Simple mixer control 'Max Overclock PLL',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 20
  Mono: 20 [100%]
Simple mixer control 'Volume Ramp Down Emergency Rate',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: '1 sample/update' '2 samples/update' '4 samples/update'     'Immediate'
  Item0: 'Immediate'
Simple mixer control 'Volume Ramp Down Emergency Step',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: '4dB/step' '2dB/step' '1dB/step' '0.5dB/step'
  Item0: '0.5dB/step'
Simple mixer control 'Volume Ramp Down Rate',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: '1 sample/update' '2 samples/update' '4 samples/update'     'Immediate'
  Item0: 'Immediate'
Simple mixer control 'Volume Ramp Down Step',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: '4dB/step' '2dB/step' '1dB/step' '0.5dB/step'
  Item0: '0.5dB/step'
Simple mixer control 'Volume Ramp Up Rate',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: '1 sample/update' '2 samples/update' '4 samples/update'     'Immediate'
  Item0: '4 samples/update'
Simple mixer control 'Volume Ramp Up Step',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: '4dB/step' '2dB/step' '1dB/step' '0.5dB/step'
  Item0: '0.5dB/step'
```

This is the arecord -l output:

```
  **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
  card 1: sndrpihifiberry [snd_rpi_hifiberry_dacplusadc], device 0: HiFiBerry DAC+ADC HiFi multicodec-0 []
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

This is the command that I run for recording the audio:

```
  arecord -vv -d 10 -f cd -t wav -D hw:1,0 foobar.wav
```

With the following output:

```
 Recording WAVE 'foobar.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
 Hardware PCM card 1 'snd_rpi_hifiberry_dacplusadc' device 0 subdevice 0
 Its setup is:
   stream       : CAPTURE
   access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
   format       : S16_LE
   subformat    : STD
   channels     : 2
   rate         : 44100
   exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
   msbits       : 16
   buffer_size  : 22052
   period_size  : 5513
   period_time  : 125011
   tstamp_mode  : NONE
   tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
   period_step  : 1
   avail_min    : 5513
   period_event : 0
   start_threshold  : 1
   stop_threshold   : 22052
   silence_threshold: 0
   silence_size : 0
   boundary     : 1445199872
   appl_ptr     : 0
   hw_ptr       : 0
      #+                                                 | 00%
```

The LED recording lamp on the Hiffyberry is continuously red but the sound level is shown to be zero.

I can't find the reason why no input can be recorded..

Comment: perhaps there is no microphone on the channel that you are recording

Comment: Microphone is attached, but there is no difference if it is plugged in or not.  Is there a need to explicitly enable the channel (s. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture last chapiter)? And if the case how?

Comment: @Samsky did you get it to record?